# Show using the formal definition of a limit that $\lim_{x\to4} \frac{x-4}{2-\sqrt x} =-4$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing

Utilize the formal definition of a limit to prove:

$$\lim_{x\to4} \frac{x-4}{2-\sqrt x} =-4$$

Comment: I've edited the tags to better reflect your intention. It would help the community if you included some of your own effort though.

Answer (score 2):

**Way 1**

$$\lim_{x\to 4}\frac{x-4}{2-\sqrt x}=\lim_{u\to 2}\frac{u^2-4}{2-u}.$$

You have that $$\frac{u^2-4}{2-u}=-(u+2),$$
and thus $$\left|\frac{u^2-4}{2-u}+4\right|=|u-2|.$$

Let $\varepsilon>0$. By taking $\delta=\varepsilon$ you'll get the result.

---

**Way 2**

Unfortunately, you may prove my first supposition, i.e. that $$\lim_{x\to 4}\frac{x-4}{2-\sqrt x}=\lim_{u\to 2}\frac{u^2-4}{2-u}.$$

So here an other way (probably the one that your teacher is waiting for). Since $$\left|\frac{x-4}{2-\sqrt x}\right|=|\sqrt x-2|,$$

you can prove that 
$$|\sqrt x-2|=|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt 4|\leq \sqrt{|x-4|}.$$

Therefore, by setting $\delta=\varepsilon^2$, you'll get the result.